# Centering a navigation bar CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a nav bar at the top of each page on my site.  Here are the HTML and CSS:

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="shifts.html">Shifts</a></li>
    <li><a href="partFive.html">Part Five</a></li>
    <li><a href="background.html">Background</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
 ul {
    z-index: 100;
    position: fixed;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 80em;
    height: 3em;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: #333;

}

li {
    float: left;

}

li a {

    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 1em;
    padding-bottom: 1em;
    width: 20em;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    text-decoration: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #111;
}

.active {
    background-color: #87372c;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px #87372c;
    color: #000000;
    font-weight: 800;
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px gold, 0 0 20px gold, 0 0 30px gold, 0 0 40px gold;
}
```

I've also set up a CodePen here: https://codepen.io/njpbray/pen/Rerabv

The bar isn't centered at all and it has an extra hanging portion to the left that doesn't react to hovering.

I'm not sure what's going on here.  I thought that making something of width 80em and settings left and right margins to auto would make it rest center.  I also thought an 80em width bar with 4 subdivision of 20em would be equally divided, but there's that bit on the left.

I would prefer to keep the bar fixed at the top though if possible.  Some pages are long, and I want the user to be able to access the nav bar anywhere on the page.

Answer (score 1):

To centralise the links, remove the `float: left` from `li` and set it to `display: inline-block`. Then simply set `text-align: center` on the `<ul>`.

The above is enough to centralise the blocks, but your content is still offset to the right of the page. To correct this, significantly shrink your `width` values. `em` is based on the font size, which is a good policy for text, but a poor choice for `width`. You can use percentages for responsiveness, or alternatively go with a fixed `px` unit depending on how 'indented' you want the links to be. I've gone with `100px` for the links in my example.

And as you're making use of a `<ul>` element, you'll also want to remove the default padding, by setting `padding: 0` on `ul`. This removes the left 'offset' you're seeing.

Finally, don't forget to set `margin: 0` on `body` to get rid of that `8px` of whitespace around the edges.

This can all be seen in the following:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

ul {
  z-index: 100;
  position: fixed;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3em;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color: #333;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 1em;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  width: 100px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  text-decoration: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #111;
}

.active {
  background-color: #87372c;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px #87372c;
  color: #000000;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-shadow: 0 0 10px gold, 0 0 20px gold, 0 0 30px gold, 0 0 40px gold;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="shifts.html">Shifts</a></li>
  <li><a href="partFive.html">Part Five</a></li>
  <li><a href="background.html">Background</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you.  This is close to the effect I want.  I don't actually want the bar to extend all the way across the page - only partially.  I also want the boxes to touch each other, but not overlap.  There's a bit of space between 'Home' and 'Shifts' when I run the snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You have the position set to fixed in your code. What you want is to set it to center.

```
ul {
    z-index: 100;
    position: center;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 80em;
    height: 3em;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: #333;

}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dgGMva

I think you might be interested in going through the CSS tutorials at w3shcools. You will benefit immensely from this:

https://www.w3schools.com/Css/

Comment: This isn't what I was asking about.  I set it to fixed so that is would follow the user as they scroll.
Also, changing fixed to center doesn't work.  The bar remains in the exact state I described in the post.

Answer (score 0):

The better way to handle what you want to achieve is to wrap you top bar in an element which take the entire width `100%` of the browser with it position property set to `fixed`  and add the list as a sub element.
And the space at the left of the first link it's due to the fact that by default the `body` tag have some margin and padding. You must remove it. the ul element have also same space padding and margin

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
header {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: blue;
}
ul {
    z-index: 100;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 80em;
    height: 3em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #333;

}
li {
    float: left;

}

li a {

    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 1em;
    padding-bottom: 1em;
    width: 20em;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    text-decoration: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}
li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #111;


}

.active {
    background-color: #87372c;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px #87372c;
    color: #000000;
    font-weight: 800;
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px gold, 0 0 20px gold, 0 0 30px gold, 0 0 40px gold;

}
```

```html
<header>
  <ul>
    <li><a class="" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="shifts.html">Shifts</a></li>
    <li><a href="partFive.html">Part Five</a></li>
    <li><a href="background.html">Background</a></li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

Comment: Thank you.  Is there a way to keep the bar fixed and centered?  I want it to move with the user as they scroll down the page.

Comment: Yes! You can try! It's fixed at the top, I set the position of the `header` element to `fixed`

Answer (score 0):

It's better with css3 and display:flex instead of float:left and inline-block

```
<header>
  <ul>
    <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="shifts.html">Shifts</a></li>
    <li><a href="partFive.html">Part Five</a></li>
    <li><a href="background.html">Background</a></li>
  </ul>
</header>

<main>
</main>
```

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

ul {
  background-color: #333;
  display: flex;
  list-style-image: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
}

li a {
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-top: 1em;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 20em;
}
li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #111;
}

.active {
  background-color: #87372c;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px #87372c;
  color: #000000;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-shadow: 0 0 10px gold, 0 0 20px gold, 0 0 30px gold, 0 0 40px gold;
}

main {
  height: 1500px;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qJbZMv

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned before: CSS3 and flex-box is supported by almost all relevant web-browsers. Use that instead. Here is a link for learning.

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/